# Run Gatling tests with karate.jar

Tags: karate

I would like to run Gatling tests (like provided in [this repo](https://github.com/ptrthomas/karate-gatling-demo)) using the all-in-one jar file of Karate. I am stuck with how to do that.

Would you be able to give me a hint on how to get started here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gatling is not supported using the JAR. You have to have a Maven project. Here is an example: https://github.com/ptrthomas/karate-gatling-demo